# removing wordpress generated code from the head section?

Tags: wp-head

Specifically, I'm talking about the following which gets added automatically:

1) `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.com/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110'></script>`

2) `<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var _wpcf7 = { cached: 1 };
//]]>
</script>`

3) `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://disqus.com/stylesheets/theme/disqus.css?v=2.0" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

4)

```
<style type='text/css'> 
#wpadminbar .quicklinks li#wp-admin-bar-stats {height:28px}
#wpadminbar .quicklinks li#wp-admin-bar-stats a {height:28px;padding:0}
#wpadminbar .quicklinks li#wp-admin-bar-stats a img {padding:4px 11px}
</style>
```

Not sure about #1, I know #2 is generated by the Contact Form 7 plugin, #3 is Disqus, and #4 is from the new admin bar in 3.1 and although I added `show_admin_bar( false );` to my functions file, the styles still show up in my head section. Anyway to get rid of all or at least some of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Normally not (that's the translation mechanism offered for javscript strings), but you can probably de-register that l10n script. But be warned that some plugins and the site might not work as intended any longer.

2) Yes, by uninstalling the contact form 7 plugin.

3) Yes, by removing the disqus plugin.

4) If disabling the admin bar did not work, please report this as a bug in [wordpress trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/). I assume it left's over a registered hook to be removed, but that's just an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

4) Plugins > WordPress.com Stats. Uncheck Admin Bar. Unfortunately, it doesn't saved but you can easily fix it.

```
Index: stats/stats.php
===================================================================
--- stats/stats.php     (revision 361838)
+++ stats/stats.php     (working copy)
@@ -351,8 +351,7 @@

                        case 'save_options' :
                                $options = stats_get_options();
-                               if ( isset($_POST['admin_bar']) )
-                                       $options['admin_bar'] = (bool) $_POST['admin_bar'];
+                               $options['admin_bar'] = isset($_POST['admin_bar']) && $_POST['admin_bar'];
                                $options['wp_me'] = isset($_POST['wp_me']) && $_POST['wp_me'];
                                $options['reg_users'] = isset($_POST['reg_users']) && $_POST['reg_users'];
```

... or use this until someone report the bug:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_stats_admin_bar_head' );
    function remove_stats_admin_bar_head() {
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'stats_admin_bar_head', 100 );
    }
```

Comment: The WordPress.com Stats issue has been fixed in Jetpack. See: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/

Answer (score 0):

You can de-register #1 by doing, but as hakre said it probably best to keep it;

```
function my_removal_thang() {
wp_deregister_script( 'l10n' );
}
add_action('init', 'my_removal_thang');
```